# Ionic cordova build error (truncated) ... v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, gradle

I recently updated android studio, and now I'm getting this error while trying to build with ionic cordova, I'm using **gradle-4.4.1**

can anyone please help me.

ionic info :

> cli packages: (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.10.3
npm               : 5.5.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

(truncated) ... v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar

```
    file:/path/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
          Required by:
              project :
        > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
          Searched in the following locations:

    file:/path/AndroidStudio/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.pom

    file:/path/AndroidStudio/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar

    file:/path/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
          Required by:
              project :
        > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2.
          Searched in the following locations:

    file:/path/AndroidStudio/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.pom

    file:/path/AndroidStudio/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar

    file:/path/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
          Required by:
              project : > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0 >
    com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.30.0
        > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2.
          Searched in the following locations:
```

Comment: try to remove the android platform and install it again

Comment: facing the same issue. @Nidhinkumar removing and adding android platform did not work.